grpcPortConfig is null even though a DI Executor window is already running
this question is related to Tosca DI
In my Tosca, when I try running DI testcase the error "grpcPortConfig is null even though a DI Executor window is already running" pops up in the scratch book.
(I'm doing it for loading data into caching db)
Is it something related to ODBC driver or?
Any help would be really appreciated!
by the way, there when i searched for caching db in my file explorer, I couldn't find it. Meaning no caching db is created.
